# Stop publishing a specific topic

Tags: ros, topic, topic-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For testing purposes I want to stop the subscription of a topic during runtime (not programatically). I would like to know if there is any tool that allows this, any command that would allow this (or an XMLRPC to the ROS master to stop that topic, or something like that).

I do not want to kill the publishing node because what I want to do is to simulate a communication link lost. I was thinking that, if there is nothing, I would use `topic_tools` relay to remap the topic and then just kill the relay, but requires modifying the remaps on the launchfile (something I would like to avoid).

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257561/stop-publishing-a-specific-topic/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use the [mux from topic_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/mux). Create two publishers (one that sends data and one which doesn't) and start with the publishing node. You can then switch to the quiet one if you want to simulate your blackout.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2017-03-22**:
Thanks a lot, that still has the problem of the relay (requires modiying the launchfiles) but is a better solution that what I had in mind :)